# How to write a java class that is a command argument in Corda?

Tags: serialization, corda

I am exploring Corda. I started with the `cordapp-template-java`. I am trying to add a flow `NewFlow` which has an Item as a member variable. Definition of Item-

```
@CordaSerializable
public class Item {
    private final String name;
    private final Party owner;

    public Item(String name, Party owner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Party getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

I am not able to invoke this flow when the nodes are deployed. this is how I invoke the `NewFlow` :

```
start NewFlow price: 100, item: { name: Item1, owner: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US" }, timeFrame: "toTimeStr=12-DEC-2019 12:26:45", parties:["O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"]
```

It throws an error -

```
No matching constructor found:
- [java.lang.Integer, com.template.states.Item, com.template.states.TimeFrame, net.corda.core.identity.Party[]]: Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `com.template.states.Item` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
```

What extra do I need to do with class `Item`? Or is this just some serialization issue?

**Edit:**

Snippet from the Flow class -

```
public class NewFlow extends FlowLogic<Void> {

    private final int price;
    private final Item item;
    private final TimeFrame timeframe;
    private final List<Party> parties;

    /**
     * The progress tracker provides checkpoints indicating the progress of the flow to observers.
     */
    private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker();

    public PostTenderFlow(Integer price, Item item, TimeFrame timeframe, Party[] parties) {
        this.price = price;
        this.item = item;//new Item(itemName, getOurIdentity());
        this.timeframe = timeframe;
        this.parties= Arrays.asList(parties);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error suggests "No matching constructor found". The issue is with the Flow class you defined. You need to have a constructor in the flow class which takes the parameters you are passing from the command line.

For example if you NewFlow class has a constructor:

```
public NewFlow(int price, String someData){
   ...
}
```

You could start the flow using:

```
flow start NewFlow price: 100, someData: "My Data"
```

Comment: I do have a constructor in there. Updated question with code snippet.

Comment: I think you would need a default constructor in your Item class.